# Mochikit or Prototype for JavaScript Framework?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Trying to figure out which to use.

Comment: Helpful discussion is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your starting you have several things to consider... one of which might be the userbase.

That said Google Trends is a great help!

[**Compare Mochikit, Prototype, jQuery and Mootools**](http://www.google.com/trends?q=Mochikit%2C+Prototype%2C+jQuery%2C+Mootools)

Hope it helps!

Comment: prototype search term != prototypejs

Answer (score 1):

Prototype extends the base Object, while MochiKit does not. This practice is [verboten](http://erik.eae.net/archives/2005/06/06/22.13.54/). So between these two I recommend selecting MochiKit. It's a very well-written and well-documented library.

Comment: I use Dojo, not JQuery, but as far as I know prototype.js is the only library to misbehave in the way that it does.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Prototype in a while, but it seemed to do a lot of what I needed. That being said, there's a larger community doing jQuery development FWIW (especially with Microsoft installing it by default in MVC and VS 2010).